# Turn on/off Leds and Torch on Windows Mobile

Tags: .net, c, .net-3.5, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

Sorry for my question.
I searched on Internet for tutorials or helps but I had not result.

I want to make some little apps for my Windows Mobile 6.X device.
I can made little programs in C **and** for ".net compact framework 3.5", but I can't do a lot for now.

How can I made a simple App that can turn on and turn off the flash-led **and** the leds of my W.M device?

Sorry for my bad english and Thank you in advice! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard API to enable Torch or Camera LED on Windows Mobile devices. You have to use the vendors specific APIs to control Torch and LED. So if you are using an Intermec device you have to use there Multimedia Resource Kit API. If you are using a Motorola device, you have to use there Motorola EMDK API to control the Torch (if provided).

Comment: In my case I have a Toshiba device with touchscreen (the model is portegeG910). I searched on Google for this API but I didn't find anything...

Comment: (I haven't found API yet. Is it possible that Toshiba has never released it?)

Comment: You need to ask your question about how to use the torch on the portege at Toshiba support. It is too special.

Comment: Thank you a lot josef, :) but you didn't say me if it's necessary to use API also to make an app that can recive input from the qwerty keyboard

Comment: For the keyboard you can use standard windows API or a hook that will look for a key or key sequence. I have several examples for global keyboard hooks but in C/C++ on my web site hjgode.de/wp

Comment: Thank you! Toshiba support seems working only for laptop and not for smartphone... anyway I think that it never released these APIs.

Comment: I found an HTC device with the same hardware and the O.S. of my smartphone. If I install HTC's .dlls file on my device Could I use HTC Apis to develop apps for my device?

Comment: Normally such device files are linked to spcific hardware and drivers and if not the same model the DLLs and APIs will not work or even load.